# Display indic font on Linux virtual console

Tags: linux, console

I want to display the Indian language on the virtual console screen. Is it possible?

What is the default console font?

I want to change the language in Linux' kernel source itself. So when the user compiles and installs it, it will be shown in Indian language only.

Comment: Is this question still relevant? You've asked another one already: http://superuser.com/questions/554136/

Comment: Both are different questions.That is about psf.we can change the console font using setfont and the new psf file.the old question was related to change in the source code